# read bytes not stored correctly in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, port

I am trying to read data from a port on linux and I then want to use this data I thought that when I write the following code each byte of the data coming will be stored in one cell in the array, but when I try to test and print it out it is always the 1st byte prints the whole data and all the other bytes are empty. does anyone know how could I store each byte read in one cell. The code is written down please tell me what am I missing ?

```
int decode_gps() {
 while(1){
 unsinged int UBX_buffer[40];
if (read(fd,&UBX_buffer,1)>0) {
//  cout<<UBX_buffer[0]<<endl;

 switch(UBX_step)     //we start from zero and increment as we go through the cases
  {
 case 0:  
if(UBX_buffer[0]==0xB5)  UBX_step++;  break; // UBX sync char 1 //check for the first data packet and go to next byte

case 1:  if(UBX_buffer[1]==0x62) UBX_step++;// UBX sync char 2 //check for the second data packet and go to the next byte

else    UBX_step=0; break;  //if first and second packets are not correct then go back and check again     

case 2:   UBX_class=UBX_buffer[2]; checksum(UBX_class); UBX_step++;  break;

case 3:   UBX_id=UBX_buffer[3];  checksum(UBX_id);  UBX_step++; break;

case 4:   UBX_payload_length_hi=UBX_buffer[4]; checksum(UBX_payload_length_hi);  UBX_step++;  break;

case 5:   UBX_payload_length_lo=UBX_buffer[5]; checksum(UBX_payload_length_lo);  UBX_step++; break;

case 6:         // Payload data read...
if (UBX_payload_counter < UBX_payload_length_hi)  // We stay in this state until we reach the payload_length
{
  UBX_buffer[UBX_payload_counter] = data;
  checksum(data);
  UBX_payload_counter++;
}
else
  UBX_step++; 
break;
case 7:   ck_a=data;  UBX_step++; break;      // First checksum byte
case 8:   ck_b=data;                           // Second checksum byte

// We end the GPS read...

if((ck_a= ck_a)&&(ck_b= ck_a))   // Verify the received checksum with the generated checksum.. 
     parse_ubx_gps();               // Parse new GPS packet...




UBX_step=0;
UBX_payload_counter=0;
ck_a=0;
ck_b=0;
GPS_timer=0; //Restarting timer...
break;

  } // End Switch 
} //end if    
} //end while loop

 close(fd);
 return(0);
}
```

Comment: It's probably a bug in how you're printing the data.

Comment: Please include compilable code.  I'm glad that your integers are not burnt (`unsinged`).  Note that reading 1 byte into an integer leads to implementation-defined behaviour unless `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)` which implies `CHAR_BIT > 8`.  You should not be passing `&UBX_buffer` to `read(fd, &UBX_buffer, 1)`, though in practice you will get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if (read(fd,&UBX_buffer,1)>0)
```

reads one byte. You are never going to get data into anything other than `UBX_buffer[0]` with that particular line.

Not sure if you meant to use:

```
if (read(fd,&UBX_buffer[UBX_step],1)>0)
```

On the other hand, you are processing only one byte at a time, so just changing `int UBX_buffer[40]` to `unsigned char UBX_buffer;`, and then use `UBX_buffer` instead of `UBX_buffer[x]` should do the trick, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which read() function is used. Does supposed to read the whole data into UXB_buffer?

and again I do not understand what you mean by
"but when I try to test and print it out it is always the **1st byte prints the whole data** and all the other bytes are empty"

If the data is more than a byte long, how the 1st byte can print the whole data?

Comment: well I just wrote   cout<<UBX_buffer[0]<<endl; after the if condition and run it on the terminal... A little delay happens then the whole data is print out. but when I try to print out //  cout<<UBX_buffer[1]<<endl; I get no data at all. thats why I am very confused.